# When Using Opacity With CSS How Can I Make The Background Transparent But Not The Text?

Tags: html, css, opacity

Basically I have a div that I want the background to be transparent.

```
<div id="modSideTop"><div id="modSideTopText">This Text Must Not Be Transparent</div></div>
```

The modSideTop div has a background image attached via css. What would the rest of the css that I need be to keep the text normal and the background transparent?

Thanks in Advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [an `rgba` color](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color) for the `background` rather than using `opacity`. For example, 50% translucent black:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

**[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/7pxrP/embedded/result,css/) on JSFiddle.**

Comment: The other option is to place both elements in a position:relative container as siblings instead of direct decendants, but upvote for rgba. Good call.

Comment: I'll try both methods the rgba will work for the colors but not the images. But it is not difficult to change the opacity of an image in PhotoShop.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am mentioning the property through which you can increase and decrease the opacity of background and that will not affect the text color its simple see the **CSS** basically you have to use the rgb color in background & alpa for opacity.

background:rgba(146,146,146,0.1);

or see the example:- http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/3/